I'm currently trying to solve a 3 islanders puzzle using a truth table and logical propositions but I can't find the solution?
Hello everyone I'm currently trying to solve this problem"
Liars, Randoms, and Truth-Tellers

Setting for more complex puzzles: You are on an island populated by three tribes.

Members of one tribe always tell the truth.
Members of the second tribe choose to tell the truth or lie, completely at random.
Members of the third tribe consistently lie.
Use 3 questions of yes/no to find answer"

However I tried using a different approach instead of using questions, which is hypothetically define statements that each one of them said and try to find a solution based on it using a truth table, that is:
Statements:
A says: B is a truth teller.
B says: B is unreliable.
C says: B is a liar.

There are these 3 categories:
Truth tellers: always tells the truth refered to as T(x) with x being either A,B or C.
Liars: L(x).
Unreliables: U(x).
The roles are exclusive, meaning that each person belongs exactly to one role.
Then I defined these propositions:
P: The speaker's statement is true.
Q: The speaker is truthful.
so if Q then P^Q > statement is true.
if not, then -Q > the statement is false.
So in other words, the form of end results should be:
1) A says "B is a truth teller" means Q > Pa=T(B) else -Pa=T(B)
2) B says "B is unreliable" means Q> Pb=U(B) else -Pb=U(B)
3) B says "B is a lair" means Q> Pc=L(B).

And then I tried constructing the truth table.
for the first row I assumed that A is truthful meaning T(A)= 1, and since A is truthful based on this assumption and A says B is truthful then B was also set to T(B)=1, as for C, C says: "B is a Liar.
For L(B)=0 (B is not a liar) because we defined it as Truth teller previously, C's statement is false.
If C's statement is false, then C cannot be truthful (()=0.)
That leaves us with two options for  : U(C)=1 (Unreliable) or L(C)=1 (Liar).
and we test U(C)=1 for this row since it's unreliable so it holds for both previously determined A and B values as T(A) and T(B) which gives following row in the table:



T(A)
U(A)
L(A)
T(B)
U(B)
L(B)
T(C)
U(C)
L(C)
PA
PB
PC
P^Q
Valid?




1
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
true
false
false
X
X



as for why Pa is true, it's because A states that B is truthteller and B is indeed truth teller, however for Pb, B states that its unreliable but in table we have U(B)=0 so it's not really unreliable, therefore its statement is false, and same case for C since it says B is liar but L(B)=0.
so now since PA is correct, we will keep value of A in it's spot, aka T(A)=1, but since in previous table we had contradictions and we found that U(B)=1 is false, then that leaves us with either U(B)=1 or L(B)=1, for this step we will pick U(B)=1, as for C, U(C)=0 is false so that leaves us with L(C)=1 or T(C)=1, but C can't be telling the truth because A states that B is truth teller so if C were to have T(C)=1 then that means it's statement that B is a liar holds, so we will give it L(C)=1 for this table, which gives this second row:



T(A)
U(A)
L(A)
T(B)
U(B)
L(B)
T(C)
U(C)
L(C)
PA
PB
PC
P^Q
Valid?




1
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
true
false
false
X
X


1
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
false
true
true
X
X



PA is false because A says B is a truth teller but in table T(B)=0 so it's not true, PB is true because B says B is unreliable and its indeed unreliable, C is true because C says B is a liar and in this case L(C)=1 so C is a liar and says B is a liar so it's true for it's case.
Going next, we have third row, now we change values of A and keep B and C? but that didn't work for me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, am I not supposed to base on the previous contradictions? what exactly to do now to finish this table and find the correct values? thanks for help and please don't close this question I already searched there is nothing like it, similar but not in same way, this is my own idea of solving it

I had trouble understanding your attempt at using a truth table.  The traditional use of a truth table, as I understand it, is illustrated by this MathSE posted question.
For problems similar to your posted question, I generally prefer deductive reason over truth tables.

B can't be a truth-teller.  Therefore, either B is unreliable, and speaking the truth, or B is a liar.
Therefore, A can not be telling the truth.
So, the only person who might (or might not) be a truth teller is C.

If you are further given that one of A,B,C is a truth teller, one of A,B,C is a liar, and one of A,B,C is unreliable, then C is the truth teller, which implies that B is the liar and A is unreliable.

Normally, if you have $~3~$ people, each of whom is either a truth teller or a liar, and you construct a corresponding truth table, the truth table will have $~2^3 = 8~$ rows.
However, with the specific question that you have posted, which includes unreliables who may lie or tell the truth, you have two general truth table oriented strategies to consider.  The ironclad approach is that there are $~4~$ choices for each person: truth teller, liar, unreliable who is speaking the truth, and unreliable who is lying.
This means that, using the ironclad approach, your truth table must have $~4^3 = 64~$ rows.  When using this approach, assuming that the problem requires that exactly one of the $~3~$ people is a truth teller, and exactly one of the $~3~$ people is a liar, you would need to consider this when determining which rows of the table may be eliminated.

The compromise approach of not distinguishing between truth tellers and unreliables who are speaking the truth, and not distinguishing between liars and unreliables who are lying, is somewhat problematic.
For example, how would you label B?  Based on B's initial statement, although you know that he is not a truth teller, you don't know whether he is lying.

If you are given that there is exactly one truth teller and exactly one liar, then the iron clad approach may be significantly shortened.  This is how I would use such an approach:
UT = unreliable who is telling the truth.
UL = unreliable who is lying.

     A    B    C
(1)  T    L    UT
(2)  T    L    UL
(3)  T    UT   L
(4)  T    UL   L

(5)  L    T    UT
(6)  L    T    UL
(7)  L    UT   T    
(8)  L    UL   T

(9)  UT   T    L
(10) UT   L    T
(11) UL   T    L
(12) UL   L    T

From B's statement, rows (5), (6), (9), and (11) can be eliminated.
Then, from A's statement, rows (1), (2), (3), and (4) can be eliminated.
Therefore, the only viable rows are (7), (8), (10) and (12), all of which have C being the truth teller.
Further, since C's statement is "B is a Liar", rows (7) and (8) can be eliminated.
Then, based on A's statement, row (10) can be eliminated.
Therefore, the only viable row is row (12).

The previous section suggests that your alternative attempt at using a truth table may be problematic.  For example, once I reached the intermediate conclusion that the only viable rows were (7), (8), (10), and (12), I had to go back and look at the exact words in C's statement.
This manual examination allowed me to conclude that rows (7) and (8) could be eliminated.
So, if you are going to attempt to invent an automated algorithm, you are going to have to symbolize exactly what each person's statement is, and somehow incorporate this symbol into the table.
This seems unworkable to me, because (for example) you would have the challenge of dealing with compound statements.
